# Razor MVC: How can I properly bind (and edit) a nested list to html elements recursively?

Tags: c#, recursion, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm having a hard time posting back my Model to the controller. With what I have done, I only get the root element and one child posted back to the controller. I know the problem is that, with a recursive function, all the html elements end up having the same name, but how can I fix it? Since I don't know how many levels my list will have, I can't use for loops :/

This is my class:

```
public class BilletesViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string IdPadre { get; set; }
    public string IdHijo { get; set; }
    public int Nivel { get; set; }
    public string Familia { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public string UnidadDeMedida { get; set; }
    public int UnidadDeMedidaId { get; set; }
    public string Merma { get; set; }
    public bool Raiz { get; set; }
    public List<BilletesViewModel> ListaMateriales { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListaUnidadesDeMedida { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my view. I'm posting the whole thing in case I'm missing something else.

```
@model DulcesDeLaRosa.Models.BilletesViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Nuevo Billete de Materiales";
    var disabled = Model.ListaMateriales != null && Model.ListaMateriales.Count > 0 ? "disabled" : "";
}

@helper ShowTree(List<DulcesDeLaRosa.Models.BilletesViewModel> ListaMateriales, int nivel, int contador)
{
    if (ListaMateriales != null)
    {
        foreach (var material in ListaMateriales)
        {
            var marginLeft = 30 * nivel;
            var marginString = marginLeft + "px;";
            var claseBorde = nivel > 0 ? "" : "";
            <div class="form-inline col-12" style="margin-top:2%">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => material.Id)
                <hr />
                <div class="col-4 delarosa-max-width">
                    <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-max-width" style="margin-left:@marginString">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => material.Material, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control delarosa-max-width" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => material.Material, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-max-width">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => material.Cantidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control delarosa-max-width" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => material.Cantidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-max-width">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => material.UnidadDeMedidaId, material.ListaUnidadesDeMedida, new { @class = "form-control delarosa-max-width" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => material.UnidadDeMedidaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-max-width">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => material.Merma, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control delarosa-max-width" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => material.Merma, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <div class="col-9 offset-1">
                            <button type="submit" id="BtnAgregar" name="btn" class="btn btn-info delarosa-background" value="Agregar|@material.Id">Agregar Hijo</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="submit" id="BtnEliminar" name="btn" class="btn btn-info delarosa-background" value="Eliminar|@material.Id">X</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            if (material.ListaMateriales != null && material.ListaMateriales.Any())
            {
                <ul>
                    @ShowTree(material.ListaMateriales, nivel + 1, contador + 1)
                </ul>
            }
            contador++;
        }
    }
}

<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <h3>Nuevo Billete de Materiales</h3>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-inline col-12 delarosa-margen-div delarosa-max-width">
        <div class="form-inline col-12 delarosa-max-width">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-inline col-11">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <label class="delarosa-alineacion-izquierda">Familia: </label>
                </div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Familia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "InputFamilia" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Familia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Raiz, new { @Value = Model.Raiz })
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <input type="submit" id="BtnAgregarRaiz" name="btn" class="btn btn-info delarosa-background" value="Agregar Raiz" @disabled />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    if (!Model.Raiz)
    {
        <div class="form-inline col-12 delarosa-margen-div">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-alineacion-centro">
                    <label class="delarosa-alineacion-centro">Material</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-alineacion-centro">
                    <label class="delarosa-alineacion-centro">Cantidad</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-alineacion-centro">
                    <label class="delarosa-alineacion-centro">Unidad</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-alineacion-centro">
                    <label class="delarosa-alineacion-centro">Merma %</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="form-group col-12 delarosa-alineacion-centro">
                    <label class="delarosa-alineacion-centro">Acciones</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin-bottom:2%" />
        @ShowTree(Model.ListaMateriales, 0, 0)
    }
    <div class="form-inline col-12 delarosa-margen-div" style="width:100%">
        <div class="col-6" style="text-align:left;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-6" style="text-align:right;">
            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Crear" class="btn btn-outline-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Has anyone tried something similar? Is there any way I can solve this?

I'd appreciate any pointers

Comment: Rather than `foreach (var material in ListaMateriales)` you need `for (var i=0;i<ListaMateriales.Count;i++)` ... `.EditorFor(model => ListaMateriales[i].Material,`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yeah that works if I loop though the first list but I don't actually know the deepness of the list, it could be from 1 to n nested for loops.

Comment: Ah. IMHO create a `Dictionary<string,BilletesViewModel>` as your model, indexed by the Id field. Just because you display the values as a tree, doesn't mean you need to bind your model as a tree.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Ok yes, I think you have a point there. I'm going to try this approach. Thank you.